# when a fusion report run through sopaui it only display data until <DATA_DS. why is that

Tags: oracle, soapui, fusion

I'm trying to run a fusion bi report through soap service. But in output XML only return values to <DATA_DS.

I tried different templates and report path and parameters also correct, but it's not working. There has used the scheduled report service to run this report.